# Outer Bounding Points of Image/Shape using C#

Tags: c#, drawing, geometry, polygon

I have some images that I'd like to draw a polyon around the outer edges. The images themselves are on transparent backgrounds and I've created an array of the pixels in the images which contain a point and are not transparent (or white).

Now, my question is: how do I draw an accurate polygon around the outer edge points? I've used a [Graham Scan algorithm](http://www.aforgenet.com/) that I read about to create a convex hull around the edges but this doesn't seem to work for objects with concavities. For example:

http://i48.tinypic.com/4s0lna.png

The image on the left gets filled in using this method with the one on the right. As you can see, it's 'filling in' a little too much.

I assume there must be some *other* algorithm or approach that can be used to solve this, but I'm not sure of where to look or what it might be called. Could anyone point me in the right direction? I'm using C#/.net and hopefully there might be something that already exists which could work along these lines.

Comment: Yeah, hit "enter" too soon while typing frantically - what a fool!

Comment: This is a very common issue when making games and trying to detect collisions between objects. It is most commonly solved using ray-tracing.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want your "polygon" to be an EXACT representation of anything that is not transparent (by alpha)? What will you use this for? Is it simply for drawing or something else? There might be other (possibly simpler) ways to do what you need.

Comment: @ananthonline yep, that's right. As you can see in the image I linked to, I'd basically like to get an 'outline' of the whisk itself and am not sure of the best way to go about doing it!

Comment: How about oldskool Region calculation? http://www.bobpowell.net/region_from_bitmap.htm. Given, you're going to have to rewrite the Region structure and some of it's methods but those are pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! I've had a look but it seems to only give a bounding rectangle, which is easy to calculate without even using a region. That would unfortunately still leave me with trying to fit a polygon to the outer bounds of the object :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the 2D "Alpha shapes" algorithm would the right choice for you.

http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Alpha_shapes_2/Chapter_main.html

Alpha shapes can be considered as a *generalization* for the "convex Hull" algorithm that allows for generation of more general shapes.

By using alpha shapes you will be having control over the level of details to be captured by the resultant shape by changing the alpha parameter value.

You can try the java applet here : http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/projects97/belair/alpha.html

to have better understanding about does this algorithm do.

Comment: I recently submitted a C# implementation of 2-D alpha shapes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625063/alpha-shape-concave-hull-algorithm-in-c-sharp/53520625#53520625).

Answer (score 1):

You can start on a pixel by pixel level, using a flood-fill approach.

```
Start in the corner, checking that it does have zero alpha.
Check the neighbours for zero alpha and iterate until we have no unchecked neighhours.
```

This gives you a mask for the image which will consist of two simply connected regions, the interior and exterior.

The set you seek then consists of:

```
   all the points in the exterior which are on the boundary of the interior.
```

You can then turn that into a polygon by:

```
Take an initial polygon that consists of all the points in the edge set
Remove redundant vertices that lie along straight edges.
```